# Read File Using Relative Path on Linux Qt

Tags: qt, path, resources, relative-path, qfile

Original one : `QFile file("/home/casper/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt");` (Work)

I have tried :

1. `"about_content.txt"`
2. `"/about_content.txt"`
3. `"~/about_content.txt"`
4. `"./about_content.txt"`
5. `"QuickRecorder/about_content.txt"`
6. `"/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt"`
7. `"~/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt"`
8. `"~/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt"`

No one works.=[

---

**My Questions**

1. What path can I use?
2. If I register the file "about_content.txt" into Resource, how can I read it into text browser?

---

The following is the entire code :

```
About::About(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::About)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(this->width(),this->height());
    QFile file("/home/casper/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt");
    if ( !file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) )
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", file.errorString());
    QTextStream content(&file);
    ui->aboutContentBrowser->setText(content.readAll());
}
```

Reference : [QT C++ GUI Tutorial 27- How to read text file and display file to a textbrowser or textEdit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvD_hFuLfzc)

---

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

**If you place your file `about_content.txt` inside build directory you can use:**

- `about_content.txt`
- `./about_content.txt`

**If you must open file right from this path `/home/casper/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt`**

- Use absolute path as you wrote in question.

**If you want use relative path**

Take a look at differrence of [relative path vs absolute path](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html). So if you place your file for example to `/home/casper/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt` and you know exactly that your build lirectory is `/home/casper/app-build` -- you can use relative path `../QuickRecorder/about_content.txt`

Take a look at [`QDir`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html) class. It already consists lots of useful methods.

**If you want to place your file to resources**

That procedure is pretty simple. Just add resource you your project and add file to your resource according to [The Qt Resource System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html). For example, you can add your file `about_content.txt` to `.qrc` file and use it in your program this way: `QFile file(":/about_content.txt");`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path of the user's home directory using the static function [QDir::homePath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#homePath).

```
QString homePath = QDir::homePath();
QFile file(homePath + "/QuickRecorder/about_content.txt");
...
```